# Conditional Types - Matching a specific nullable type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to match for a nullable type in a conditional type:

```
interface Unwrapped { dummyProp: string; }
interface UnwrappedArray<T extends Unwrapped> extends Array<T> { }
interface Wrapped<T extends Unwrapped> { unwrapped: T; }

type ToPropertyWrapped<T, K extends keyof T> =
    T[K] extends UnwrappedArray<infer ArrayElementType> ? Wrapped<ArrayElementType>[] :
    T[K] extends Unwrapped ? Wrapped<T[K]> :
    NonNullable<T[K]> extends Unwrapped ? Wrapped<NonNullable<T[K]>> | undefined :
    T[K];
```

But I'm getting this error...

> error TS2344: Type 'NonNullable<T[K]>' does not satisfy the constraint 'Unwrapped'.
>
> Type 'T[K]' is not assignable to type 'Unwrapped'.

...when passing in `Wrapped<NonNullable<T[K]>>`. How do I eliminate this compile error?

```
// example use that works... just have the compile error above
interface PropType extends Unwrapped {
}

interface Test extends Unwrapped {
    prop: PropType;
    nullableProp: PropType | undefined;
    arrayProp: PropType[];
    numberProp: number;
}

let t: ToPropertyWrapped<Test, "prop">;         // Wrapped<PropType>
let u: ToPropertyWrapped<Test, "nullableProp">; // Wrapped<PropType> | undefined
let v: ToPropertyWrapped<Test, "arrayProp">;    // Wrapped<PropType>[]
let w: ToPropertyWrapped<Test, "numberProp">;   // number
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current way I've found to do this is to use a type parameter as an alias:

```
type ToPropertyWrapped<T, K extends keyof T, NonNullableValue = NonNullable<T[K]>> =
    T[K] extends UnwrappedArray<infer ArrayElementType> ? Wrapped<ArrayElementType>[] :
    T[K] extends Unwrapped ? Wrapped<T[K]> :
    NonNullableValue extends Unwrapped ? Wrapped<NonNullableValue> | undefined :
    T[K];
```

I'm guessing it's a limitation of the compiler that the code in the question does not work.